# Windows Server 2008 R2, the Indexer service cannot index the custom properties of a document

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, indexing-service

On Window 2008 R2 server, when I try to use the custom property of indexing service like:

```
<meta name="decription" content="this is description details" />
```

I cannot get the decription property.

I found the this hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947265
But this hotfix is not working for Window 2008 R2

Need your help.

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that we need to grant permission on the drive to be used on indexing service.